# "Missing screenshots" After uploading an app to the appstore?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, itunes

I've been trying to upload my game to the appstore for a couple of hours already, this process drives me crazy to be honest, I think that Apple didnt do much of a great job explaining how to do that,

Anyhow, after actually uploading my game, I got a red icon there, and it sais "Missing screenshots"

After looking in google and such, I realized that it may have something to do with the device family I've been building the game for, so I changed it to iPhone only,

But now when I tried to re-upload my game, I couldn't.
The Application Manager doesn't let me upload anything, and I can't even delete the app from the list and restart the process,

I'd be grateful to hear what I could do to fix it and get this annoying process behind me.
Thank you so much

Comment: Did you reject the Binary after submitting the first time?

Comment: @Sooper No? I just uploaded, looked at the status and saw this error, I dont know how to reject it or how to get it back to the "Waiting for upload" status

Comment: you don't need to re upload your game.Just upload some screenshots for iPhone5 will solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Login to iTunes Connect and go to 'Manage Your Applications'
2. Select your app and then select the current version
3. Under 'Links' header, select 'Binary Details'
4. On the top right hand corner of the page you'll see 'Reject This
   Binary', click this and confirm
5. Go back to your app's page and then press 'Ready to Upload Binary'
   again. and continue as before when you first uploaded.

If you don't see 'Ready to Upload Binary', you just need to wait for the rejection to go through (you should receive an email when this is done).

Comment: Thank you so much! I just rejected it so I can't upload it yet, but yea, you definitely helped me here! thanks (again)

Comment: Why you want to reject binary? all you need to do is to upload 5 screenshot for `iPhone5` under app details on app's iTunesconnect profile. thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Whether its an app that is made for a specific country or global, or whether it is for the iPhone,iPad or Universal, if you have set the "Localization Native Development" key in the info.plist file to true, you'll have to upload screenshots specific to each region.